# Changing request header when AJAX request rejected by MediaWiki

Tags: jquery, ajax, mediawiki-api

I sent the AJAX request below to the MediaWiki API, and the following message appeared in the console:  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://preview.cs50.io' is therefore not allowed access.`  I'm not doing anything nefarious, and I'm using the cloud9 IDE. I tried adding the `headers` option to my AJAX request (a simple object with an origin key that had my domain as a value), but the API didn't like that either.

The responses on here indicate that the programmer should not be able to set an `origin` header for security reasons, which makes sense. Still, I need access to the API. Do I have any recourse?

This is the first time I have worked with the MediaWiki API and docs.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // future search parameter provided by user
        var search = "french";
        // AJAX request options for MediaWiki API
        var ajaxOptions = {
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: {
                action:"query",
                list:"search",
                srsearch:search,
                // titlesnippet may be more desirable, try both
                srprop:"snippet",
                srlimit:"50",
                pwpprop:"title",
                // may not be necessary given use of srlimit above, try and see
                pwplimit:"50",
                format:"json"
            }
        };
        // AJAX request
        $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(updateDOM);

        function updateDOM (json) {
            $("#message").html(JSON.stringify(json));
        }

    });
```

Comment: Try as jsonp request

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 1):

This was simply a lesson in reading the docs more closely. The MediaWiki docs go on forever.  It's easy to get lost in their API forest when looking at the many trees therein, especially if you have limited experience with APIs generally and/or no experience with MediaWiki.

If making your AJAX/CORS request in a manner similar to the one above, simply add . . .

```
origin:"*"
```

to the end of the data object inside the ajaxOptions object, and the situation should be resolved.